# SQL: Count amount of comments for each post written by specific author

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, join

I always felt like I needed to improve my SQL knowledge, I am trying to, but still no success to find an answer to my question.

I have 2 tables: `Post` and `Comments`.

`Post` table has a PK `PostID, Username, Title, Content`.

`Comments` table has a PK `CommentID, FK PostID, Username, Content`.

`Username` in `PostID` is the `Username` of the post's author, in `Comments` it is commenter's `username`. Everything else should be pretty self explanatory.

**Main challenge: I want to select all posts made by that specific author and display amount of comments for each post AND display zero if no comments are found. All in one query (if possible?)**

So far the closest, I've gotten to was this:

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(*) as CommentAmount
FROM Posts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Comments c
ON p.PostID = c.PostID
WHERE p.Username = 'author1'
GROUP BY c.PostID
```

It works in a way, but doesn't display neither Post data, nor CommentAmount (0) if no comments exist for that PostID - which makes sense since it does not find any p.PostID that has the same c.PostID. How to make it display 0 CommentAmount as well? Is it even possible?

Here is the sample SQL Fiddle I've set up so you could test as well!: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8941


**UPDATE: I made a little mistake in the schema... sorry guys. Fixed in the fiddle above^**

**UPDATE2: Thanks everyone for amazing answers! Funny how most solutions work perfectly on SQL Fiddle but seem not to work on my DB on the cloud, using MySQL Workbench... I'll have to look into that now then, thanks everyone!**

Comment: That's a really good question. I wish there were more like this on SO. Prepared fiddle to work on, it's a dream. Great job ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?:

```
SELECT p.*,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Comments WHERE PostID=p.PostID) AS num_comments
FROM Posts p
WHERE p.Username = 'author1'
```

Comment: Return's just 0 comment amount all the time :(

Comment: @ExacT I misunderstood your question. corrected. please note that this query is concise and use no `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about the performance and ANSI compatibility, I had no idea about any of those. Your remade query works flawlessly and I take your word about `GROUP BY` clause. I ended up using your solution anyway by the way. Marking this as an accepted answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You only need to adjust your query by adding `GROUP BY` and changing `COUNT()` aggregate argument to point to `Comments` so that it will enable storing value `0` when there are no comments for a particular post.

It doesn't matter which column from `Comments` you will put inside `COUNT()`, since every column has a `NULL` value when JOIN condition is not met.

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(c.CommentID) AS CommentAmount
FROM Posts p
LEFT JOIN Comments c
ON p.PostID = c.PostID
WHERE p.username = 'author1'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Would have picked you as an accepted answer, but @Harsh was 2 minutes faster, so :)

Comment: No problem, its fine enough for me that it helped you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5ab1/5)

```
SELECT kk.*, IFNULL(_aa.total, 0) AS total_comments
FROM Posts AS kk
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT aa.PostID, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM Posts AS aa
    LEFT JOIN Comments AS bb
    ON aa.PostID = bb.PostID
    GROUP BY bb.PostID
) AS _aa
ON kk.PostID = _aa.PostID
WHERE kk.Username = 'author1'
```

Also check [**this**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and [**this**](http://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/) about `GROUP BY` and nonaggregated columns in `SELECT` clause.

Comment: I don't think that `COUNT()` can ever return `NULL` value. There is no need to call `IFNULL()` function to check that.

Comment: Oh, yes, its because of LEFT JOIN (it's 3 am here I can't thing very clear...).

Comment: Totally understandable :)

Comment: Looks kinda over-complicated, but I would still like it if it would work, but it doesn't somehow for me, sorry :( Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: I bet that it doesn't work because of table name `Post` instead of `Posts` I used in the query. Keep in mind those two links I have in my answer about nonaggregated columns in SELECT clause.

Comment: It needs to be like this to select the correct values for columns that are not in `GROUP BY` clause (the links explains it better).

Comment: +1 @KostasMitsarakis is right. As I commented on an accepted answer, OP's query is not valid ANSI compatible query. non-aggregated column cannot be SELECTed. (So, I think my answer is best ;)

Answer (score 1):

Make a small change to your query:

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(c.CommentID) as CommentAmount
FROM Posts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Comments c
ON p.PostID = c.PostID
WHERE p.Username = 'author1'
GROUP BY c.PostID
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! Very little difference from my initial query as well!

Comment: Performance consideration) if 100 posts have 100 comments, then internally 10,000 rows are populated and reduce by 100 output by `GROUP BY`.

SQL Syntax) note that this query (and OP's query) runs in MySQL though, it is not ANSI compatible, so that this query returns a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Your only problem is your fiddle XD everything work fine u just have no author1 with post with no comment ! look i addded one http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f2f6/1

Comment: Wow, ye inserted "3" to the author, not Title... my bad. Thanks for a notice! My real solution is not on the fiddle, so I had to transfer, what a stupid mistake, but problem won't be solved with my query tho :(

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.*, (select COUNT(*) from comments c where c.PostID = p.PostID)
FROM Posts p
WHERE p.Username = 'author1'
```